# Executing a function before JQuery $destroy

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a piece of code like this

```
$('#id').on('$destroy', function(){
                ...
            }
})
```

I want this function to be trigered by the destroy event, but it should execute before the destroy, right now it is executing after it. Can anyone suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you make `$destroy` a callback of this function?

Comment: you can call a function that call the destroy as a callback.

Comment: but I need to trigger my function on destroy, so that is again going to look the same as what I have now.

Comment: You cant control the order at which events in javascript are fired. So adding a function with $destroy as a callback to this function and then calling it would be your best/safest bet.

Comment: this sounds like an `X-Y` problem. Explain at higher level and in more detail what objective is

Answer (score 1):

Use `$broadcast` as a proxy to call `$destroy`:

```
function beforeDestroy(event, options) 
  {
  console.log(String().concat("Event: ", event,"Old: ", options.oldValue, "New: ", options.newValue);
  /* 
  execute stuff before calling destroy 
  ....
  ....  
  */

  /* Manually call destroy when done */
  $scope.$broadcast("$destroy");
  }

/* Bind Callback */
$scope.$on("beforeDestroy", beforeDestroy)

/* Trigger Broadcast Event */
$scope.$broadcast("beforeDestroy", { newValue: $scope.id++, oldValue: $scope.id });
```

> $transclude functions no longer attach $destroy event handlers to the transcluded content, and so the associated transclude scope will not automatically be destroyed if you remove a transcluded element from the DOM using direct DOM manipulation such as the jquery remove() method.
>
> If you want to explicitly remove DOM elements inside your directive that have been compiled, and so potentially contain child (and transcluded) scopes, then it is your responsibility to get hold of the scope and destroy it at the same time.
>
> The suggested approach is to create a new child scope of your own around any DOM elements that you wish to manipulate in this way and destroy those scopes if you remove their contents - any child scopes will then be destroyed and cleaned up automatically.
>
> Note that all the built-in directives that manipulate the DOM (ngIf, ngRepeat, ngSwitch, etc) already follow this best practice, so if you only use these for manipulating the DOM then you do not have to worry about this change.

**References**

- [Scope: $broadcast](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$broadcast)
- [AngularJS Changelog: 1.3.0-rc.4 Breaking Changes](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#breaking-changes-20)